# How can I receive emails for scheduling failures in my Luigi data pipeline?

Tags: python, email, luigi

I'm using Luigi for a Data pipeline of mine. I'd like to receive emails that inform me about scheduling failures (ideally any type of failure really). I've tested mail sending using
`luigi TestNotificationsTask --local-scheduler --email-force-send`
and received those Emails so I'm pretty sure nothings wrong with my mail settings. But when I run a workflow of my own e.g.
`python workflow.py --local-scheduler --email-force-send`
and get the terminal output

```
    - (...)
    ...

This progress looks :( because there were tasks whose scheduling failed
```

I receive no mail whatsoever. Is there any setting for this I missed in the docs and if not how would I go about implementing mail sending on scheduling failures on my own.